# MVC BeginForm - passing parameters to controller using GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action

I am implementing a search filter to one of my application's views. I struggle at getting routeValues passed to controller action using `@Html.BeginForm()` and GET request.

The action accepts the following properties:

```
public ActionResult Books(int id, string type, string search)
{
    //rest of the code
}
```

The View's search box looks like this:

```
@model ILookup<string, CityLibrary.Models.Library.Book>
.... 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Books", "Collections", new { id = Model.First().First().CollectionId, type = ViewBag.BookType }, FormMethod.Get, null))
{
    <div class="input-group col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBox("search", null, new { @class = "form-control form-control-fixed-width", @placeholder = "Filter title..." })
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

The problem occurs when I am submitting the search box. The controller action gets the `id` and `search` string, but `type` is always `null`, even though `ViewBag.BookType` is not `null`. Fiddler shows this:

> GET /Collections/Books/2?search=searchterm

Which seems to be completely ignoring `type` parameter in the request.

Source code in browser:

```
<form action="/Collections/Books/2?type=available" method="get">
    <div class="input-group col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control form-control-fixed-width" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Filter title..." type="text" value="" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Does it have something to do with GET method? I would like to avoid POSTing as I would have to write another controller action with basically the same code.

**EDIT:** It seems that the problem occurs when I try to use GET request. POSTing the form actually passes all the parameters to the controller action. Why is that?

Comment: It suggests that `ViewBag.BookType` **is** `null`. Add a `<div>@ViewBag.BookType</div>` in your view and confirm it.

Comment: It does not. The `@ViewBag.BookType ` is also used in the View at the top (a simple `if/else` statement to display a correct header). I also tried to hardcode the type property. `@using (Html.BeginForm("Books", "Collections", new { id = Model.First().First().CollectionId, type = "available" }, FormMethod.Get, null))` also returns `type` of `null`.

Comment: Do you actually have a route defined with `..../{id}/{type}` (if not then a route value cannot be added)

Comment: I do not want to specify a custom route. I would like this all to be passed as querystring, like: `/Collections/Books/2?type=available&search=searchterm`.

Comment: The add a hidden input for `type`. And if you have the default route, then you do not even need the `new { id = Model.First().First().CollectionId }` code

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution. Would you like to write an answer so I can mark it as the correct one? I can only mention that I used `Html.Hidden("type", (string)ViewBag.BookType)` and the `type` property is successfully passed to controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is in accordance with the [HTML specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm), In particular for a form with `method="get"`, (my emphasis)

> **Mutate action URL**
>
> Let destination be a **new URL** that is equal to the action except that its <query> component is **replaced** by *query* (adding a U+003F QUESTION MARK character (?) if appropriate).

So the query string value in your form's `action` attribute is replaced with the query string generated by the name/value pairs of the form controls.

Two options to solve this:

1. Remove the `new { type = ViewBag.BookType }` from the `BeginForm()` method and add a hidden input for the parameter

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="type" value="@ViewBag.BookType" />
   ```
2. Create a custom route definition for the method so that `type` is added as a route parameter, not a query string value (note this must be before the Default route)

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Books",
       url: "Collections/Books/{id}/{type}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Collections", action = "Books" }
   );
   ```

   so that your current `BeginForm()` code will generate

   ```
   <form action="/Collections/Books/2/available" method="get">
   ```

and the form submit will result in a url of `Collections/Books/2/available?search=searchterm`

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning (especially for those not so experienced in MVC like me), that the custom `MapRoute` has to be placed **before** the `Default` one, otherwise it's not working.

Comment: @Dandry, I already did - at the end of the second point - enclosed in brackets :)

Comment: Pardon me. This is what happens when one is too much focused on source code rather than plain text. Thank you alot!